# how to put files in ram

Tags: linux, centos, unix, shell

I have a server with 30 Gb ram and i have a script that  put a (.ts) file (10mb) in /var/www/html/tv  and script replace (.ts) file every 2 mintues.

so my question is: can i mount this folder /var/www/html/tv  in **RAM** so  all files in this folder /var/www/html/tv will be located in ram and not in hdd

i read somewhere that i need to use a command like this but dont know if this is what i need

```
mount -t tmpfs none /var/www/html/tv/ -o size=2g
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't need to do this for such small files.

But if you want, you can use the [`vmtouch` utility](https://hoytech.com/vmtouch/) to lock a directory into RAM.

Comment: so that was just example, actually i have 100 .ts files which are replaced every 10 seconds  and the total size is 1 gb

Comment: @Gloytoshtyqo Okay.

Answer (score 1):

this command

```
mount -t tmpfs -o size=4g tmpfs /var/www/html/tv/
```

will store /var/www/html/tv in ram

u can check it via

```
df -m
```